# Facebook used to need to LIKE a page first, before they can like any content (photo, comment), when this has taken out?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Facebook used to need to LIKE a page first, before they can like any content (photo, comment), when this has taken out?

When Non-fan want to like any post of the page, (e.g user comment, photo, or other content). When Non-fan click on the like, Facebook will ask them to like the page before they can do that, I just found out Facebook does not work like this any more.

May I know since when this had changed?

We are planning to having a contest to ask Facebook user to like our fan page, before the like to the photo, but with current Facebook setting, user can just like the photo without like our fan page.

Comment: I have been using Facebook since 2007, and I have not had to 'like' a fan page first, before liking or posting any content...

Comment: I remember very clearly from my experience is my friend ask me to like his comment in a fan page. I have to like the fanpage first before I can click the like, else they not allow to do it.

Comment: I think should be my mistake, maybe not Like action, is posting action. I just able to search this article - http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/09/21/friend-activity-comment-without-liking/

Comment: @Shiro Well, that's your answer right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contests/competitions/sweepstakes/etc

> must not use Facebook features or functionality as a promotion’s registration or entry mechanism. For example, the act of liking a Page or checking in to a Place cannot automatically register or enter a promotion participant

and

> must not condition registration or entry upon the user taking any action using any Facebook features or functionality other than liking a Page, checking in to a Place, or connecting to your app. For example, you must not condition registration or entry upon the user liking a Wall post, or commenting or uploading a photo on a Wall

and

> must not use Facebook features or functionality, such as the Like button, as a voting mechanism for a promotion

See [Facebook's Promotion Guidlines](http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php) for the rest of rules and regulations.

Comment: Another great (and accepted!) answer, which is downvoted to -1 without giving any comment on what is wrong! I see, that Web Applications users are the same group of cowards, like on Stack Overflow, that loves to downvote without giving author any guides, what could / should be fixed or what caused them to downvote particular piece of text. Shame, very shame! :|

Answer (score 0):

The change went into effect September 15th, 2011.

Comment: Do you have a link to where this was said? I am only seeing blog posts from unofficial Facebook blogs

Comment: That was when I started seeing the comment boxes on non-liked pages.  At the time I looked around for an official announcement but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use FBML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<fb:visible-to-connection>
FANS-ONLY CONTENT
<fb:else>
<div id="non-fans">CONTENT FOR NON-FANS</div>
</fb:else>
</fb:visible-to-connection>
</div>
```

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-fan-pages-content-for-fans-only-static-fbml/